# How to remove spaces within folders using PHP

Tags: php, directory

Given the path /books/Aaronovitch, Ben/Rivers of London/9780575097568, how could I use PHP to rename the actual folder names to remove the spaces?

Comment: Please more details, and code. What have you tried?

Comment: I should have stated before, this is on a windows OS. Actual path would be c:/server/www/blah/blah/books/Aaronovitch, Ben/Rivers of London/9780575097568.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
echo renameRecrisive(__DIR__, "xx_x/yyy yyy/zz z/fff");
```

Output

```
 /public_html/www/stac/xx_x/yyy_yyy/zz_z
```

Function

```
/**
 * 
 * @param string $path Current path ending with a slash 
 * @param string $pathname Path you cant to rename
 * @param string $sep Optional Seprator
 */
function renameRecrisive($path, $pathname, $sep = "_") {
    $pathSplit = array_filter(explode("/", $pathname));
    $dir = $path;
    while ( $next = array_shift($pathSplit) ) {
        $current = $dir . "/" . $next;
        if (! is_dir($current)) {
            break;
        }
        if (preg_match('/\s/', $next)) {
            $newName = str_replace(" ", $sep, $next);
            rename($current, $dir . "/" . $newName);
            $dir .= "/" . $newName;
        } else {
            $dir .= "/" . $next;
        }
    }

    return $dir ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Php function str_replace:

```
$newPath = str_replace(' ', '', $path);
```

and then use the rename function.

```
rename($path, $newPath);
```

Comment: That works for the path, but I need to rename the actual folders themselves. Will this still work to rename the folders?

Comment: should have stated before, this is on a windows OS

Comment: Actual path would be c:/server/www/blah/blah/books/Aaronovitch, Ben/Rivers of London/9780575097568.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get what you mean. Please quote your Strings and also tell me exactly what you want to be changed.

Comment: Have you also tried to test my code? It removes every space in a single path.

Answer (score 0):

This will walk down each level of the hierarchy, renaming each component if it contains spaces.

```
$patharray = split('/', $path);
$newpatharray = str_replace(' ', '', $patharray);

$oldpath = $patharray[0];
$newpath = $newpatharray[0];
$i = 0;

while (true) {
  if ($patharray[$i] != $newpatharray[$i]) {
    rename($oldpath, $newpath);
  }
  $i++;
  if ($i >= count($patharray) {
    break;
  }
  $oldpath .= "/".$patharray[$i];
  $newpath .= "/".$newpatharray[$i];
}
```